# no value from $_POST

Tags: php, javascript, html, post

No value is sent to `$_POST['addEdit']` variable , please help.

HTML code:

```
<form name='frm' method='POST' action=''>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr class="heading">
<td style="width:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name='check_all' onClick='checkAll();' /></td>
<td class="head">App Name</td>
.
.
<?php
//some embeded php (here is the addEdit component)
.
.
echo '
<td id="row_'.$row['id'].'" style="display: none;">
 <input type="text" name="addEdit" id="addEdit_row_'.$row['id'].'" value="" size="4"/></td>
<td>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="A"  onClick="addObs('.$row['id'].'); return false;"/>
';
</td>
.
.//end oh php code
?>
<!-- end of html code -->
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
 //echo 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
 if (isset($_POST['addEdit']))
 {
  echo 'post: '.$_POST['addEdit'];
 }
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, why are you echoing a load of HTML for a few simple variables?! Madness

Comment: I`m sorry, the script was not written by me I just do minor updates and I`m a very nob in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Did you close `<form>` tag ?

Try to:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Ok but what do you have in `var_dump` ?

Comment: string(0) ""  this is the output :(

Comment: As a whole `$_POST` ? `$_POST` should be in the worst case an empty array but not string ! So you must overwriting this `$_POST` with some other value.

Comment: However `<input type="text" name="addEdit" ...` has no value param.

Comment: sry, Ive dumped my var
this is what you've asked:
array(2) { ["addEdit"]=>  string(0) "" ["add"]=>  string(1) "A" }

Comment: I`ve added value="", still no value in POST :(

Comment: `value=""` gives you empty string -> `string(0) ""` :) Try to set some value -> `value="test"` and in `$_POST` you will get this `test` value.

Comment: Yes, thats true, but I don`t think I need any value parameter because I take the value from the input field; what should I do ? :(

Comment: I said you to set `value` in your `HTML`. I do not know what have you done now, but in your `HTML` code you give us there is empty `value` parameter in `addEdit` input. If you set something there, you will have it in `$_POST` in `PHP.

Comment: If I write the parameter value="test" then "test" would come through POST, but I want the value parameter to be populated with the string from the input box;

Comment: In you write down something in this `input` it will be `POST`'ed to `PHP`.

Comment: I wish, that`s why I wrote this topic

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<form name='frm' method='POST' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>'>
```

Comment: Empty `action` param gives current addres also.

Comment: Ok, my bad. The addEdit input element has no value, but when the form is submitted it should be present in the $_POST global. Can you paste the HTML of the page when fully loaded so we can see what is echoed?

Comment: <td id="row_30126" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="addEdit" id="addEdit_row_30126" size="4"/>
</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="add" value="A"  onClick="addObs(30126); return false;"/>
</td>

Comment: from what I can see your PHP output is probably going to be "post: "... there is no value for the addEdit element. If it was <input type="text" name="addEdit" id="addEdit_row_30126" value="addEdit_row_30126" size="4"/> then your PHP output would be "post: addEdit_row_30126"

Comment: could you write exactly the value parameter ?

Comment: You would type something into that textbox which will be stored in the POST global, so if you type "hello" into the addEdit text field, the POST global would have an element named "addEdit" and it's value would be "hello". If you set the value dynamically using PHP, then it will appear in the text box and it will be that value that is submitted unless you type something different.

Comment: I don't know how to set the value dynamically :(

Comment: in your php code, you've got value="", you can set the value there using a variable, that would be setting it dynamically.

Comment: so, you saing that I should read the value from addEdit component, write it to a variable $temp, then set value=$temp on the same addEdit component, it makes no sense to me, sry

Comment: If you want to be able to type something into the addEdit text box, then forget about setting the input value (<input type="text" value="???"). If you don't type anything in the addEdit text box, and submit the form, $_POST['addEdit'] will be set to "" (empty string)... else it will equal what you typed into the text box. I'm not sure what else you are trying to do.

Comment: my problem is: the the string typed in the addEdit text box doesn't get sent to the $_POST variable; 
what should I modify so I can receive something through $_POST['addEdit']  ?